# How to group objects and make calculations for each group of objects efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm working on a javascript application where I get some data from an API, this is how a few records of the dataset look like:

```
    {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 
    05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "45.665", nodeId: "1", …}
    {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-                                        
    05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "47.602", nodeId: "9", …}
    {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 
    05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.287", nodeId: "12", …}
    {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 
    05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.932", nodeId: "27", …}
    {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 
    05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "56.918", nodeId: "9", …}
```

As you can see it's a set of objects, now what I want to do is, group this set of objects by nodeId. So I can do calculations on every nodeId. I want to have the avarage duration of every nodeId. But I don't really know where to start/how to do this efficiently.

I think it'll have to be with some filter/map/reduce, am I correct? Can't quite wrap my head around this just yet

Thanks in regards

Comment: I'm assuming the data that you receive from the API comes back as an array of objects?

Comment: What should the expected output be?

Comment: @KobanDavis that is correct, an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object and store the sum, count and average for each `nodeId`.

```js
var data = [{ eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "45.665", nodeId: "1" }, { eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "47.602", nodeId: "9" }, { eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.287", nodeId: "12" }, { eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.932", nodeId: "27" }, { eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10: 56: 28", duration: "56.918", nodeId: "9" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { duration, nodeId }) => {
        r[nodeId] = r[nodeId] || { sum: 0, count: 0, average: 0 };
        r[nodeId].sum += +duration;
        r[nodeId].average = r[nodeId].sum / ++r[nodeId].count;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce` to group by `nodeId` as well create the array of duration. Then you can use `map` to get the average of your duration

```js
const input = [
{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "45.665", nodeId: "1"},
{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "47.602", nodeId: "9"},
{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.287", nodeId: "12"},
{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.932", nodeId: "27"},
{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "56.918", nodeId: "9"}];

const groupByNodeId = Object.values(input.reduce((accu, {nodeId, duration, ...rest}) => {
    if(!accu[nodeId]) {
        accu[nodeId] = {...rest, nodeId, durations : []};
    } 
    // console.log(accu[nodeId]);
    accu[nodeId].durations.push(Number(duration));
    return accu;
}, {}));

const getSum = (arr) => arr.reduce((accu, num) => accu+num);
const output = groupByNodeId.map(({durations, ...rest}) => ({...rest, durationAvg: getSum(durations)/durations.length}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want - use `reduce`:

```js
const data = [{eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "45.665", nodeId: "1"}, {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019-10:56:28", duration: "47.602", nodeId: "9"}, {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.287", nodeId: "12"}, {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15- 05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "5.932", nodeId: "27"}, {eventAction: "area", sessionId: "20190515|04434531", timestamp: "15-05-2019 10:56:28", duration: "56.918", nodeId: "9"}];

const res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.nodeId] = acc[curr.nodeId] ? acc[curr.nodeId].concat(curr) : [curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```